# logout in jsp not working due to browser redirection

Tags: jsp

I want to log out from my the account in my project . So i wrote an jsp code as below

```
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%session.invalidate();%> You have logged out. Please <a href="adminlogin.html"><b>Login</b></a>
```

but whenever i click on browser back button it's going to the main admin page but it should not go back to the previous page . I should disable the browser from going to the admin main page . It should only happen through log in. please help me***

Comment: Use [filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) instead of write code in JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

[see here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/)

Comment: it's not working an error is shown
element on page show not allowed at this point